# What set is this? Star Wars, lots of greys, light and dark

Tags: set-identification

What set do these bags belong to? It is the same Star Wars set.

[image: Star Wars, lots of greys, light and dark]

[image: Star Wars, lots of greys, light and dark]

[image: Star Wars, lots of greys, light and dark]

Comment: Could you post a photo of the other side, so we can see more of the pieces not obscured by the 4 label?

Answer (score 6):

[75292-1 The Razor Crest (The Mandalorian Bounty Hunter Transport)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75292-1)
[image: 75292-1 The Razor Crest (The Mandalorian Bounty Hunter Transport)]

This is all from the first large photo which has the wheels (didn't see the second large photo until after the links were fixed). The small photo perplexed me for quite a while as well, so I'm just going to ignore it now.

Based on

- Light Bluish Gray Plate, Round Half 3 x 6 with 1 x 2 Cutout
- Dark Bluish Gray Plate 4 x 4 Corner
- Yellow Technic, Axle 7L

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit confused by this. I needed to squint (and zoom the image), but I can see at least 3 units of [Plate, Modified 4 x 6 with Trap Door Hinge](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92099#T=C&C=85) in dark bluish grey:

[image: part 92099]

...plus one [60485 technic axle, 9L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60485&idColor=3) in yellow:

[image: part 60485]

Performing a [search for sets containing those parts](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=92099&itemSeq1=3&colorID1=85&itemNo2=60485&itemSeq2=1&colorID2=3&itemNo3=&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=&in=S) yields set 75292-1 "The Razor Crest, but the [parts list for the set](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75292-1) does **not** include any 6x10 or 6x12 plates, nor any 4x12 plates.

There's a few sets which include several trapdoor plates plus 4x12 light bluish grey plates (millenium falcon, AT-AT, UCS super star destroyer), but none of those sets do have any 9L yellow axles.

Better photographs are needed; or, at least, clarification on the sizes of light bluish grey plates in that bag.

---

Edit: The new photographs have clarified the situation. The 6xN plates are dark grey (and not light grey), and the 4x12 plate is really two 4x6s. As @RSchulz has pointed out, this is indeed the Razor Crest.

Comment: Just add another bag from the same set

Comment: Ah! It's not a 4x12 - it's two pieces, but you can't tell because of the white band covering them both. I also spent a long time trying to reconcile that.

Comment: Set 70323-1 Jestro's Volcano Lair also has the trap door and axle, but only one trap door, which I didn't notice at the time, oops.